# Google assistant on raspberry pi segmentation fault with device model id and device id

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

When I run the command to initiate assistant:

```
googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project_id assistpi
--device_model_id assistpi-c2bd1
```

It gives me this response:

> device_model_id: assistpi-c2bd1 device_id:
>   8DC785496FB8796C3F913BE0F9B63FF1
>
> Segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, registration bug.
You can delete your device and re register it (from the start)
Take a look here [Google Assistant on Raspberry pi Segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50440960/google-assistant-on-raspberry-pi-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seemed that I didn't properly turn on the Google Assistant API in Google Cloud.